# How can is draw rectangle based on two date?

Tags: d3.js

Below is the code i use to draw axis and circle. I need to add rectangle based on two date and placed it under the circle. Appreciate your help. Thanks.

[image]

```
                    let scale: any = d3select.scaleTime()
                        //.domain([d3select.min(data), d3select.max(data)])
                        .domain([new Date(2020, 0, 1), new Date(2021, 0, 1)])
                        .range([20, axes_width - 800]);


                    let x_axis: any = d3select.axisBottom(scale)
                        .scale(scale);


                    axes_svg.append("g")
                        .call(x_axis);

                    var myData = [new Date(2020, 3, 1), new Date(2020, 6, 1)];



                    axes_svg
                        .selectAll('circle')
                        .data(myData)
                        .enter()
                        .append('circle')
                        .style("fill", "#69b3a2")
                        .attr('r', 6)
                        .attr('cy', 40)
                        .attr('cx', function (d) {
                            return scale(d);
                        });
```

Comment: Providing minimal reproducible sample would help, [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: So you need to add rectangles at the same horizontal location (`x`) but different vertical location (`y`)? Just use the same code you applied to add the circles (`axes_svg
                        .selectAll('circle')
                        .data(myData)...`) for adding the rectangles (just with the attributes associated to the `rect` object) and have a different `cy` value.

Comment: @JoeBe i want to add a rectangle which has width that depends on 2 dates. Like a task, which has start date & end date. still not sure how to do it.

Comment: How about using a `line` and assign the `x1` and `x2` values to the dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem here is that you pass all dates in a one dimensional array. Instead of having

`var myData = [new Date(2020, 3, 1), new Date(2020, 6, 1)];`

like you do for the circles, you should have something like this:

`var myRecData = [ {"startDate": new Date(2020, 3, 1), "endDate": new Date(2020, 6, 1)}, {"startDate": new Date(2020, 4, 1), "endDate": ....];`

And then access it with `d.startDate` and `d.endDate`

**EDIT:**

Based on your last comment I recreated the whole code (**for future questions please  add a complete reproducible code, so people who want to help you can test it fast...**):

```
<body>
<div id="mainDiv"></div>
<script>
    const width = 500
    const height = 500

    const axes_svg = d3.select("#mainDiv").append("svg")
      .attr("viewBox", [0,0, width, height])
      .attr("width", "100%")
      .attr("height", "100%")

    let scale = d3.scaleTime()
        //.domain([d3select.min(data), d3select.max(data)])
        .domain([new Date(2020, 0, 1), new Date(2021, 0, 1)])
        .range([20, width - 200]);

    let x_axis = d3.axisBottom(scale)
        .scale(scale);

    axes_svg.append("g")
        .call(x_axis);

    var myData = [new Date(2020, 3, 1), new Date(2020, 6, 1)];

    axes_svg
        .selectAll('circle')
        .data(myData)
        .enter()
        .append('circle')
        .style("fill", "#69b3a2")
        .attr('r', 6)
        .attr('cy', 40)
        .attr('cx', function (d) {
            return scale(d);
        });


    var testdata = [{ start: new Date(2020, 1, 1), close: new Date(2020, 3, 1) }];

    axes_svg
        .data(testdata) 
        .append("rect") 
        .style("fill", "#00abff") 
        .attr("x", function (d) { return scale(d.start); }) 
        .attr("y", 80) //distance from axis 
        .attr("width", function (d) { return scale(d.close) - scale(d.start); }) 
        .attr("height", 30); //height
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: My data : `var testdata = [{ start: new Date(2020, 0, 0), close: new Date(2020, 3, 0) }];`

Comment: For x already ok using start date, but i'm having problem to set the width. I want it to end at close date.       `axes_svg
            .data(testdata)
            .append("rect")
            .style("fill", "#00abff")
            .attr("x", function (d) {
                return scale(d.start);
            })
            .attr("y", 80) //distance from axis
            .attr("width", function (d) {
                return scale(d.close - d.start);
            })
            .attr("height", 30); //height`

Comment: `return( scale(d.close) - scale(d.start));` ok.I replace with this code for width and it works. thanks